# What type of accuracy should I reported in research paper?

Tags: neural-networks, validation, accuracy, keras

I have read some research papers on the classification task of deep learning, and now I am doing my own. After investigating some research paper which also provided the source code for reproducing their research, I saw many of them reported validation accuracy instead of overall accuracy (testing accuracy, in Keras it is the output of model.evaluate()). I think they should report testing accuracy instead of validation accuracy. According to my understanding, the accuracy comes from cross-validation is also validation accuracy, not overall accuracy for testing dataset.

My question is, should I report testing accuracy or validation accuracy for benchmarking with other researcher..?

Comment: Related: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Comment: Yes, I think accuracy is not the best, but it is the most commonly used in the community.